# C++ .NET DLL wrapper to a C# COM DLL (built with Mono)

Tags: c#, c++, unix, dll, mono

I have a C++ .NET COM DLL wrapper to a C# COM DLL and I was curious, would it be possible to build the wrapper using Mono on UNIX? When I try, I get a lot of errors like these:

```
$>/opt/mono/bin/mcs /target:library *.cpp -recurse:'*.cpp' -warn:0 -out:my.dll -r:System.Windows.Forms.dll -r:System.Data.dll -r:System.Xml.Linq.dll

/AssemblyInfo.cpp(2,18): error CS1024: Wrong preprocessor directive
/AssemblyInfo.cpp(4,6):  error CS1041: Identifier expected, `namespace' is a keyword
/AssemblyInfo.cpp(4,22): error CS1001: Unexpected symbol `;', expecting identifier
/AssemblyInfo.cpp(42,1): error CS8025: Parsing error
```

I'm still new to COM and Mono, so I apologize if this idea is fundamentally flawed.

PS. If there's an interest I can include the actual code, but I'm more curious about the general mechanics.

Comment: Mono is a C# compiler, not a C++ compiler, which is why it's generating errors when trying to compile your C++ code.

Comment: @dmakaitis Thanks! I guess I had assumed it did all .NET and not just C#. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COM components are not cross plateform, and it works only on Windows OS, the equivalent cross plateform alternative is [XPCOM](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPCOM) used by Firefox for example.